# Does java handle packets differently on ubuntu vs windows

Tags: java, ubuntu, openssl, vps, packets

I have a vps and I wanted to install a java server programm on it.
It contains ssl but I believe that is not used for java. At least it doesn't seem really encrypted.
The weird thing is that sending from the ubuntu server 2 bytes get added that I didn't specify, and some bytes change. I know need to know why it doesn't do that on windows and does on my ubuntu vps...
And if it is different how to solve it.

I use printWriter and then flush to the client.
and the "ISO8859-1" to encrypt the packets and those are not strings or numbers just plain bytes that I sended.

```
protected Socket socket;
protected BufferedReader socketIn;
protected PrintWriter socketOut;
protected LoginServer server;

public static final byte[] LOGIN_SUCCESSBYTE = {(byte)0x01, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00,         (byte)0x00, (byte)0x01, (byte)0xFF, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00};

this.socketOut.write(new String(LoginServer.LOGINHEADER, "ISO8859-1"));
this.socketOut.flush();
this.socketOut.write(new String(LoginServer.LOGIN_SUCCESSBYTE,"ISO8859-1"));
this.socketOut.flush();
```

the packet send by windows
    00000000  EC 2C 4A 00 01 00 02 00  00 00 FF 00 00 00 00 00   .,J..... ........
    00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ........ ........
    00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ........ ........
    00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ........ ........
    00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00         ........ ......

the packet send by ubuntu
    00000000  C3 AC 2C 4A 00 01 00 02  00 00 00 C3 BF 00 00 00   ..,J.... ........
    00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ........ ........
    00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ........ ........
    00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ........ ........
    00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ........ ........

Comment: Show us the code please.

Comment: Please include the code that exhibits this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String` is not a container for binary data, and `Writer`s are for character data, not binary. Just write the bytes directly, with an `OutputStream`, not a `Writer`. Java doesn't handle packets at all, let alone differently, but it has different default character encodings on different platforms.

Comment: Not what I was hoping for to find, because I needed to change alot of things in my code. Still fixed it mostly. Need to finish yet so if I finish and all works I will flag this one answered.